# How to import a Sqlite3 database dump in windows

Tags: sqlite

I want import the schema and data into different machine.

I have created a Sqlite3 Database dump  with .dump file, but unable to import it.
I don't know how to import it at some other machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

cat dumpfile.sql | sqlite3 my_database.sqlite

Or

sqlite3 my_database.sqlite < export.sqlite3.sql

Comment: I am trying this in windows.

Comment: have you tried          "sqlite> .read <filename>"   from sqlite promt

Comment: yes I did c:\Sqlite> .read bkp.db
'.read' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: can you please try .import  <filename> in sqlite promt